# Error when trying to run a Python script in Power BI

Tags: python, machine-learning, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning

I keep getting the below error when trying to run python script in power BI.
I have tried uninstalling and re-installing all numpy , pandas but to no avail.

Please i would appreciate some assistance to get this running

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:148: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PythonScriptWrapper_6bb79068-43bc-4932-896d-bb3c9e1e2a45\PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing all numpy , pandas but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try installing the mkl-service package, as the error message says?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Anaconda Python distribution you are probably pretty aware that

**you have to ACTIVATE conda**,

before you can run PBIDesktop.exe. This especially true if you want to include the C-libraries like the ones required for numpy.

Simple as that.

Comment: The windows store version is called PBIDesktopStore.exe and can be found in {C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps}